# Executing .exe file with parameters in C#

Tags: c#, .net, batch-file

I am automating some batch files into a single C# application but not having much luck.  I have the following batch file (and another 3) that I am trying to write in C#

```
"C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe" /path:c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ASP.NETWebAdminFiles /vpath:"/asp.netwebadminfiles" /port:61569 /clr:4.0 /ntlm
```

Here is the C# code I have found online but it fails:

```
using (Process proc = new Process())
{
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = "iisexpress.exe";
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/path:c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ASP.NETWebAdminFiles /vpath:/asp.netwebadminfiles /port:61569 /clr:4.0 /ntlm";
    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    proc.Start();
    proc.WaitForExit();
    Console.Out.WriteLine(proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
}
```

I get the following, with no help from Google:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception'
>   occurred in System.dll

Comment: Add quotes around the parameter values?  `@"/path:""c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ASP.NETWebAdminFiles"" /vpath:""/asp.netwebadminfiles"" /port:61569 /clr:4.0 /ntlm"`

Comment: What does the exception *message* say?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Exception:Thrown: "The system cannot find the file specified" (System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception)
A System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception was thrown: "The system cannot find the file specified"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give `Process.StartInfo.FileName` the full path to your exe:

```
proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe";
```

Comment: I tried this and did not get an error, but the command window appeared with no text.  Does it mean it is still working in the background?  Sorry for my lack of knowledge.

Comment: I've tested this using LINQPad and i see the site registered properly. Check your IIS configuration to make sure it worked